# Filepicker can't select a file on Windows 8, IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, filepicker.io

I have defined a filepicker widget like this:

```
<input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="--" data-fp-mimetypes="image/jpg, image/jpeg, application/pdf" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-multiple="true" onchange="on_file_picker_change(event,)" data-fp-button-text="Browse for files">
```

This is working fine on the Mac with Chrome, Safari and Firefox. It also works fine on Windows 8 with Firefox. However it isn't working on Windows 8 with IE10. Drag and drop doesn't work at all, and clicking on "Choose a file" bring up the file browser but the "Files of type" field is marked "Any File (undefinedundefinedundefined)", and choosing a file of the type my widget allows is not possible.

Any clues as to what the problem might be? I have not tested with other versions of IE.

Comment: Update: if I click on "having trouble?", The widget allows me to select file(s). It uploads them but does not show any upload progress information.

Comment: The choose a file button works fine in their online demo. The drag 'n' drop issue also exists on their demo, and throws an Invalid Argument errors, so it looks like filepicker.io isn't IE compatible, at least for that feature.

Comment: Hi there. We're aware of these issues and looking into them. Thanks.